# android ICS left caret resource

Tags: android

The new Android design docs mention use of an Up caret: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

The up caret seems to be proper for navigation throughout Android - is there a proper way to add this caret? It seems unintuitive that I should just modify the icon image to include it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also add the caret by setting setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) on the ActionBar. Be sure to react to the menu item when selected.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.d(TAG, "Home Icon Item Selected");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also show / hide the whole home affordance (including the up caret) via setDisplayShowHomeEnabled().

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're asking where you can find the images for the "caret", they're in the `platform/data/res/drawable-hdpi` folder (in your SDK location). The files are called `ic_ab_back_holo_[dark|light].png`. You can see it in the [github repo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_ab_back_holo_light.png) too. The standard procedure of copying to your local resources folder applies here, since you can't reference them (they're not exposed).

Comment: You got lucky, I just searched for those images myself yesterday, so I had the knowledge fresh! Glad I could help :)

Comment: For Holo and Holo.Light, the files you are looking for are ```ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png``` and ```ic_ab_back_holo_light_am.png```